# Better Print statement in Python using format strings?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("=" * 100 + '\n' + "Can I be more elegant?" + '\n' + "=" * 100)
```

Is there a better elegant to print this?

Output

========================

Can I be more elegant?

========================

Comment: `print("{0}\nCan I be more elegant?\n{0}".format("=" * 100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 3.6 or later, you can use the cool new f-strings.

```
print(f"{'='*100}\nCan I be more elegant?\n{'='*100}")
```

Prior to that, you can use `format`.

```
print("{0}\nCan I be more elegant?\n{0}".format('='*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example was better. print("We have x = %i" %x) because you are working with a string object. It takes less memory than working with 2 string objects and an int.

Since you are asking with a python3 tag, here is a newer format for python string formatting using str.format

dic = { 'x': '1'}
print("We have x = {x}".format(**dic))

or you can do this positionally:

print("The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2))

This also works with 2.6 and 2.7.